# Global variable not picking child functions values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have used a variable `$extra_charges` which is being used in functions `woo_add_extra_fee()` and  `wl8OrderPlacedTriggerSomething()`. For some reason it always prints zero(even after the if conditions are met).

```
<?php
    $extra_charges=0;

    public function woo_add_extra_fee() {
        global $woocommerce;
        $available_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
        $current_gateway = WC()->session->chosen_payment_method;
        if($current_gateway=='cod'){
            global $extra_charges;
            $current_gateways_detail = $available_gateways[$current_gateway];

            $disable_cod_adv = $current_gateways_detail->settings['disable_cod_adv'];
            if($disable_cod_adv && $disable_cod_adv=='yes'){return $totals;}

            $current_gateway_id = $current_gateways_detail->id;
            $current_gateway_title = $current_gateways_detail->title;
            $extra_charges_id = 'woocommerce_'.$current_gateway_id.'_extra_charges';
            $extra_charges_type = $extra_charges_id.'_type';
            $extra_charge_min_amount = (float)$current_gateways_detail->settings['extra_charge_min_amount'];
            $extra_charges = (float)$current_gateways_detail->settings['extra_charges'];
            $extra_charges_type = $current_gateways_detail->settings['extra_charges_type'];
            $roundup_type = $current_gateways_detail->settings['roundup_type'];
            $extra_charges_msg = $current_gateways_detail->settings['extra_charges_msg'];
            if(!$extra_charges_msg){$extra_charges_msg = 'COD Charges';}

            //get cart total
            $total = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;

            if($extra_charges){
                if($extra_charges_type=="percentage"){
                    $total = $total + round(($total*$extra_charges)/100,2);
                }else{
                    $total = $total + $extra_charges;
                }
                if($roundup_type>0)
                {
                    $extra_add = $roundup_type -($total%$roundup_type);
                    $total = $total+$extra_add;
                    $extra_charges = $extra_charges+$extra_add;

                }

                //$this->current_extra_charge_min_amount = $extra_charge_min_amount;
                //$this->current_gateway_title = $current_gateway_title;
                //$this->current_gateway_extra_charges = $extra_charges;
                //$this->current_gateway_extra_charges_type_value = $extra_charges_type;
                $extra_fee_option_taxable = 0;
                //if cart total less or equal than $min_order, add extra fee
                //$extra_fee_option_label = sprintf(__('%s Extra Charges <small>for purchase less than %s</small>','askoracle'),$this->current_gateway_title,woocommerce_price($this->current_extra_charge_min_amount));
                $extra_fee_option_label = $extra_charges_msg;
                //$extra_fee_option_label = get_woocommerce_currency();
                $extra_charges = 0;
                if (get_woocommerce_currency() == "SAR")
                    $extra_charges = 20;
                if (get_woocommerce_currency() == "QAR")
                    $extra_charges = 20;
                if (get_woocommerce_currency() == "AED")
                    $extra_charges = 0;
                if (get_woocommerce_currency() == "EGP")
                    $extra_charges = 90;
                if (get_woocommerce_currency() == "JOD")
                    $extra_charges = 4;
                if (get_woocommerce_currency() == "BHD")
                    $extra_charges = 2;
                if (get_woocommerce_currency() == "KWD")
                    $extra_charges = 2;
                if (get_woocommerce_currency() == "OMR")
                    $extra_charges = 2;
                if (get_woocommerce_currency() == "LBP")
                    $extra_charges = 7500;
                if($extra_charge_min_amount>=$total || empty($extra_charge_min_amount)){
                    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee($extra_fee_option_label, $extra_charges, $extra_fee_option_taxable );
                }
            }
        }

    }

}




$hook_to = 'woocommerce_thankyou';
$what_to_hook = 'wl8OrderPlacedTriggerSomething';
$prioriy = 111;
$num_of_arg = 1;    
add_action($hook_to, $what_to_hook, $prioriy, $num_of_arg);

function wl8OrderPlacedTriggerSomething($order_id){
      global $extra_charges;
      //do something...
      update_post_meta( $order_id, "cod_fee", $extra_charges);
}
```

Comment: You’re missing some of the functions you are calling and I also don’t see where “woo_add_extra_fee()” is being called, can you include that? I’d start with stopping those functions at different junctions, like right before each if statement confirming the values of the if statements to ensure every step is going through.

Comment: @JoshWhitlow: How do I stop the functions?

Comment: exit; stops the script wherever you put that.